# Field 'csrf' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, csrf

I'm trying migrate an PHP app from one server to other, I copy the files and DB, upload everything without any error, but when I run the app I got this error:

Internal Error Server

Field 'csrf' doesn't have a default value

Unfortunately I don't have any idea how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

There is most likely an input field in an authentication page that  is meant to contain a crsf token.But somewhere, something went wrong in your app and it is unable to generate or insert the token.Also, your DB has a field `csrf` with a `NOT NULL` value.

You have two options:

- Manually search for what went wrong when generating,inserting or sending the csrf(Reccommended)
- or Change the DB field `csrf` to NULL or give it another default value(Not reccommended at all).It can lead to [Cross-Site Request Forgery](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/csrf&ved=2ahUKEwixmcqj0-_pAhUOmRQKHSRxB0AQFjAOegQIDRAi&usg=AOvVaw1igD764EwnMCpycIu5TP6F)